# Canot load string into javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use google chart to load an array of data. My string input is

```
var data = "[['Time', 'TasksRunning'],[1.9520154, 0]]";
var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```

I get the message

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Not an array
```

What is wrong with my data?

Comment: It requires an array, you gave it a string, what's confusing about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a string, not an array. Notice the quotes.

If you remove the quotes you will have an array.

Comment: I just this second realised that. Its input read from a file hence why it's in string format. Is it possible to convert it from a string to an array?

Comment: @NZJames If it satisfies the JSON format, you can use `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Are single quotes not supported? I just tried that and it says invalid character

Comment: needs double quotes always

Comment: `JSON.parse()` should be able to convert it to an array.

Comment: @Mike Not with single quotes around the strings.

Comment: @NZJames How did this solve your problem, since you said in other comments that you're reading the string from a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable's value is in quotes, which makes it a string. Remove those and just have the [] around the comma separated values to make it an array.

```
var data = [['Time', 'TasksRunning'],[1.9520154, 0]];
```

Edit:
Since you're reading from a text file, you'll need to do some manipulation to create the array out of the string. Perhaps something like the following:

```
//Original data
var data = "[['Time', 'TasksRunning'],[1.9520154, 0]]";
//Exclude the outer brackets
var parsed = data.substr(1,data.length-2);
//Split into separate parts
var parts = updatedData.split('],[');
//Recreate the new array
var arr = [];
for(var a = 0; a < parts.length; a++) {
  //Remove the brackets from the parts
  var val = parts.replace(/[\[\]]/g,'');
  arr.push(val);
}
//Yields: ["'Time', 'TasksRunning'", "1.9520154, 0"]
```

Comment: For simplicity I wrote it as a string. I'm actually reading the string contents from a file and passing it in as a variable to the method. If the above string is the contents of the file, how can I load it as a javascript array, is there any way?

Comment: @NZJames Updated to accommodate your comment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is JSON-formatted (using ALWAYS double quotes instead of single quotes) you can just use `JSON.parse`:

```
var string='["Hello",["one","two"],3]';
var array=JSON.parse(string);
```

This will create an array with tree elements: a string, another array and a number

Pro-tip: Use always single quote characters when coding, so you won't have to escape the double quote characters when creating a JSON string or a HTML/XML tag with attributes.

Comment: *Use always single quote characters when coding* not the best advice. Single quotes can mean different things to double quotes in some languages. Creating a string literal with JSON or HTML directly in JavaScript if often a sign that something could be done better.

Comment: That always is refering to Javascript, I know that in Java you must use double quotes because single ones is only for characters

Answer (score 0):

I hate to suggest it, but if the origin of the file is trusted you can use `eval()` to convert the string to an array.

```
var data = eval("[['Time', 'TasksRunning'],[1.9520154, 0]]");
var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
```